# Choose the correct option if $ y=e^{2\pi i/7} $and $ x =y+y^2+y^4$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $y=e^{2\pi i/7} $ and let $x  =y+y^2+y^4$then,

which of the following given option is correct

1)$x\in Q$

2)$x\in Q(\sqrt D)$ for some $ D>0$

3)$x\in Q(\sqrt D)$ for some $ D<0$

4)$x\in iR$

#### My thinking:

$x=e^{(2\pi i/7)} +e^{2(2\pi i/7)} +e^{4(2\pi i/7)}$ =$e^{2\pi i/7}(1+e^2+e^3)$

Here,  $(1+e^2+e^4)$ is real number and $e^{(2πi/7)}$ is complex number  so  option $4$ is clearly true.

I don't know about the other option(s). Please help  me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=e^{2\pi i /7}+e^{4\pi i /7}+e^{8\pi i /7} = e^{2\pi i /7}(1+e^{2\pi i /7}+e^{6\pi i /7})$ not $e^{2\pi i /7}(1+e^2+e^3)$. Also what is R? What are you trying to show?

Comment: ohh,,,,my mistake @Rdrr   i was trying to show that option 4 is correct

Comment: It is still incorrect. $e^{2(2\pi i/7)}\ne e^{2\pi i/7}\cdot e^2$

Comment: $1,2,4$ are the quadratic residues in $\mathbb{F}_7^*$ hence $x$ is a [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) $\!\!\pmod{7}$. Option 4) cannot be correct since $x+\overline{x}=-1\neq 0$.

Comment: thanks a lots @JackD'Aurizio sir

Comment: (-1+$\sqrt{-7}$)/2

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y$ is a root of $y^7-1$, but since $y\neq 1$ it is actually a root of $(y^7-1)/(y-1)=y^6+y^5+y^4+y^3+y^2+y+1$.  Check that

\begin{align*}
x^2 &= (y+y^2+y^4)^2 \\
&= y^2+2y^3+y^4+2y^5+2y^6+y^8 \\
&= y+y^2+y^4 + 2 (y^6+y^5+y^3) \\
&= x + 2(-1-x) \\
&= -x-2
\end{align*}
so $x$ is a root of $x^2+x+2$.  Since the discriminant of that quadratic is $-7$, it's irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, and the correct answer must be 3)

Comment: thanks a lots @sharding4